# SQL Server 2016 - Comma separated string values by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, group-by, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------------+
| Id | Project Type    |
+----+-----------------+    
| 1  |   Restoration   |
| 1  |   Outreach      |
| 1  |   Education     |
| 2  |   Restoration   |
| 2  |   Education     |
+----+-----------------+
```

And I want my table to look like:

```
+----+-------------------------------------+
| Id | Project Types                       |
+----+-------------------------------------+    
| 1  |   Restoration, Outreach, Education  |
| 2  |   Restoration, Education            | 
+----+-------------------------------------+
```

I'm having trouble setting this up as I am new to SQL Server. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There's no way to reliably replicate the row order.  Needs an ordinal of some sort.  Is it reverse alphabetical?

Answer (score 1):

You want string aggregation. In SQL Server 2017 or higher, use `string_agg()`:

```
select id, string_agg(projet_type, ',') projet_types
from mytable
group by id
```

In earlier versions, you would typically use `for xml path`:

```
select id, 
    stuff(
        (
            select ', ' + project_type as [text()]
            from t t1
            where t1.id = t.id
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, ''
    ) project_types
from t
group by id
```

Comment: OP mentioned 2016

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: yes, thanks for pointing this out... That was quite obvious though, right in title! I fixed the answer.